# Can DocumentationFile and GenerateDocumentationFile be used together in .Net project file?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, xml-documentation

I'm writing a small analyzer for C# projects that checks if the XML documentation generation is present and set up correctly. There are two options for to specify XML documentation:

- An older `DocumentationFile` option
- A newer `GenerateDocumentationFile` flag. If the flag is set to true MSBuild should generate a XML documentation file with the project's name in the project's output directory.

Can both of these options be specified explicitly in the project file?
Will the values from these options be combined or one of the options will be ignored?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They both don't need to be set. If `DocumentationFile` is not empty, then `GenerateDocumentationFile` will set to `true` in an MSBuild target.

If you set `GenerateDocumentationFile` to `true`, then a default value for `DocumentationFile` will be set based on the project file name.

Relevant MSBuild targets

```
  <!-- Handle XML documentation file settings -->
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(GenerateDocumentationFile)' == ''">
    <GenerateDocumentationFile Condition="'$(DocumentationFile)' == ''">false</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile Condition="'$(DocumentationFile)' != ''">true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(GenerateDocumentationFile)' == 'true' and '$(DocumentationFile)' == ''">
    <DocumentationFile Condition="'$(MSBuildProjectExtension)' == '.vbproj'">$(AssemblyName).xml</DocumentationFile>
    <DocumentationFile Condition="'$(MSBuildProjectExtension)' != '.vbproj'">$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(AssemblyName).xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(GenerateDocumentationFile)' != 'true'">
    <DocumentationFile />
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
So If I understand correctly they both can be set explicitly in the project file. If GenerateDocumentationFile is set to false then the DocumentationFile is ignored, if GenerateDocumentationFile  is set to true than MSBuild will use DocumentationFile specified in the project file. If no DocumentationFile  is specified MSBuild will generate it,

Comment: Yes, you understand it perfectly!

Comment: The case when you have both options and GenerateDocumentationFile is set to false is still a bit unclear to me. Will the <DocumentationFile /> declaration override the existing DocumentationFile option?